# Insert new line after any amount of numeric characters

Tags: sed

I need to insert a new line, or delimiter, in a text file after a "numeric" string consisting of 10 numbers, then a "-", then either 1 to 4 numbers...

Example:

```
randomtext,1234567890-1234blahblah
```

Should be:

```
randomtext,1234567890-1234, blahblah
```

Or:

```
randomtext,1234567890-1234
blahblah
```

Note that the set of numbers will always be 10 characters, the numbers after the - will either 1,2,3 or 4 characters.

I've used sed a lot for similar tasks, but can't find a way to work with the last set of numbers which vary from 1 to 4 characters....

I really hope someone can help!

Many thanks!

Comment: see https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#BRE-syntax .. you can use quantifiers to limit character matching to between 1-4 times..

Comment: Be careful with the phrase "any amount".  There are zero numeric characters between the `r` and the `a` in random text, but I don't think you want to insert a newline there.  (This will matter if you try using metacharacters like `*` in a regex)

Answer (score 0):

```
$ echo randomtext,1234567890-1234blahblah | 
  sed -E 's/[0-9]{10}+-[0-9]{1,4}/&\n/'

randomtext,1234567890-1234
blahblah
```